# How to add details from column to form title - SharePoint 2010

Tags: 2010, edit

Is it possible to add additional column info to the form title.  For example, when we open a list item to view it's content along the top in the title is the SharePoint List + item Title. I'd like to also include the item's reference number (which is in a separate column).  This is so when reviewing it I don't have to keep scrolling back to this info.

I am using SharePoint 2010

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Sharepoint Designer
Open your form in advanced mode
Goto below section .You will get this in first 1-2 lines .

```
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderPageTitle" runat="server">
<SharePoint:listformpagetitle runat="server"/>
</asp:Content>
```

Remove

```
 <SharePoint:listformpagetitle runat="server"/>
```

Add whatever you want like below

If you want a value of a column, set the column name in the Property attribute

```
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderPageTitle" runat="server">
<SharePoint:ListItemProperty runat="server" Property="Status"/>
</asp:Content>
```

If you want a constant text

```
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderPageTitle" runat="server">
Welcome Page
</asp:Content>
```

Note: As a safety measure please try this on a test form first

Comment: HI, Please mark it as answer if it works for you, so someone seeking for answer will get helped
Thanks